# Uber API scopes do not appear in the dashboard page

Tags: uber-api

I have recently registered my first app on the Uber API and see the dashboard of the app but can't get around the authorization scopes.

The [docs](https://developer.uber.com/docs/riders/guides/scopes) say "Under the Auth tab, click Request Full Access next to a privileged scope".

However, I don't see a corresponding section on the dashboard page.

Also, [another docs page](https://developer.uber.com/docs/riders/references/api/v1.2/estimates-time-get) says "Please contact your Uber Business Development representative or Uber point of contact to get access to this API" but [there are only](https://developer.uber.com/support) StackOverflow (here), Q&A Google Group (site 403) and Twitter.

How can I contact them or can I make it through the dashboard? I know this is not somewhat a technical issue though.

Comment: I am facing the same issue. I sent an email to `getuberpay@uber.com` asking for contacts on how to get an Uber Business Development rep - in hope that they will direct me to the right person, but I haven't received a response yet. Maybe if many people reached out, they might respond. I also tried their Twitter page and no response. If you come across a good contact, please post here.